# What is tape-based autograd in Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I understand `autograd` is used to imply automatic differentiation. But what exactly is `tape-based autograd` in `Pytorch` and why there are so many discussions that affirm or deny it.

For example:

[this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-pytorch-autograd-tape-based/13992)

> In pytorch, there is no traditional sense of tape

and [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-the-gradient-tape/62886)

> We don’t really build gradient tapes per se. But graphs.

but not [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/autograd_tutorial.html)

> Autograd is now a core torch package for automatic differentiation. It
> uses a tape based system for automatic differentiation.

And for further reference, please compare it with `GradientTape` in `Tensorflow`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are different types of automatic differentiation e.g. `forward-mode`, `reverse-mode`, `hybrids`; ([more explanation](https://justindomke.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/a-simple-explanation-of-reverse-mode-automatic-differentiation/)). The `tape-based` autograd in `Pytorch` simply refers to the uses of **reverse-mode** automatic differentiation, [source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-a-tape-based-autograd-system/1400/2). The **reverse-mode** auto diff is simply a technique used to *compute gradients efficiently and it happens to be used by backpropagation*, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928746/9215780).

---

Now, in [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/autograd_tutorial.html), Autograd is the core torch package for automatic differentiation. It uses a `tape-based` system for **automatic differentiation**. In the forward phase, the `autograd` tape will **remember all the operations** it executed, and in the backward phase, it will **replay the operations**.

Same in [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff), to differentiate automatically, It also needs to remember what operations happen in what order during the forward pass. Then, during the backward pass, TensorFlow traverses this list of operations in **reverse order to compute gradients**. Now, TensorFlow provides the [`tf.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) API for automatic differentiation; that is, computing the gradient of computation with respect to some inputs, usually [`tf.Variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable). TensorFlow **records** relevant operations executed inside the context of a [`tf.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) onto a **tape**. TensorFlow then uses that tape to compute the gradients of a **recorded** computation using [**reverse mode differentiation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation).

So, as we can see from the high-level viewpoint, both are doing the same operation. However, during the custom training loop, the `forward` pass and calculation of the `loss` are more explicit in `TensorFlow` as it uses `tf.GradientTape` API scope whereas in `PyTorch` it's implicit for these operations but it requires to set `required_grad` flags to `False` temporarily while updating the training parameters (weights and biases). For that, it uses [`torch.no_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html) API explicitly. In other words, TensorFlow's `tf.GradientTape()` is similar to PyTorch's `loss.backward()`. Below is the simplistic form in the code of the above statements.

```
# TensorFlow 
[w, b] = tf_model.trainable_variables
for epoch in range(epochs):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # forward passing and loss calculations 
    # within explicit tape scope 
    predictions = tf_model(x)
    loss = squared_error(predictions, y)

  # compute gradients (grad)
  w_grad, b_grad = tape.gradient(loss, tf_model.trainable_variables)

  # update training variables 
  w.assign(w - w_grad * learning_rate)
  b.assign(b - b_grad * learning_rate)


# PyTorch 
[w, b] = torch_model.parameters()
for epoch in range(epochs):
  # forward pass and loss calculation 
  # implicit tape-based AD 
  y_pred = torch_model(inputs)
  loss = squared_error(y_pred, labels)

  # compute gradients (grad)
  loss.backward()
  
  # update training variables / parameters  
  with torch.no_grad():
    w -= w.grad * learning_rate
    b -= b.grad * learning_rate
    w.grad.zero_()
    b.grad.zero_()
```

FYI, in the above, the trainable variables (`w`, `b`) are manually updated in both frameworks but we generally use an optimizer (e.g. `adam`) to do the job.

```
# TensorFlow 
# ....
# update training variables 
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([w_grad, b_grad], model.trainable_weights))

# PyTorch
# ....
# update training variables / parameters
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Comment: nice examples!!

Answer (score 6):

I suspect this comes from two different uses of the word ['tape'](https://openreview.net/pdf/25b8eee6c373d48b84e5e9c6e10e7cbbbce4ac73.pdf) in the context of automatic differentiation.

When people say that [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) is not tape-based, they mean it uses Operator Overloading as opposed to [tape-based] Source Transformation for automatic differentiation.

> [**Operator overloading**] relies on a language’s ability to redefine the meaning of functions and operators. All primitives are overloaded so that they additionally perform a tracing operation: The primitive is logged onto a ‘tape’, along with its inputs to ensure that those intermediate variables are kept alive. At the end of the function’s execution, this tape contains a linear trace of all the numerical operations in the program. Derivatives can be calculated by walking this tape in reverse. [...]
> OO is the technique used by PyTorch, Autograd, and Chainer [37].
>
> ...
>
> **Tape-based** Frameworks such as ADIFOR [8] and Tapenade [20] for Fortran and C use a global stack also called a ‘tape’<sup>2</sup> to ensure that intermediate variables are kept alive. The original (primal) function is augmented so that it writes intermediate variables to the tape during the forward pass, and the adjoint program will read intermediate variables from the tape during the backward pass. More recently, tape-based ST was implemented for Python in the ML framework Tangent [38].
>
> ...
>
> <sup><sup>2</sup> The tape used in ST stores only the intermediate variables, whereas the tape in OO is a program trace that stores the executed primitives as well.</sup>

- [Automatic differentiation in ML: Where we are and where we should be going](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11530)